# Git: Automatically commit submodule with the same message

Tags: git, github

I have a working project as follows:

```
project/
  .git/
  .gitmodules
  submodule/  # submodule is a git submodule
```

I am hoping that, whenever I made a commit in the submodule. The parent module `project` will commit `submodule` with the same commit message. I tried to implement this using `commit-msg` hook:

```
#!/bin/bash
# project/.git/modules/submodule/hooks/commit-msg
cd $(dirname ${BASH_SOURCE[0]})/../../../..
git commit submodule -m "$(cat $1)"
```

But this does not work as I get the error message 'error: pathspec 'submodule' did not match any file(s) known to git'. The reason seems to be because the `git commit` command will also invoke the `commit-msg` hook, leading to a recursive call.

May I know how should I do this properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`commit-msg` is probably not the best place to do this, because it's meant for processing the commit message, and the submodule commit has not been made when it's called.

This `post-commit` hook works for me:

```sh
COMMIT_MSG=$(git log -1 --pretty='format:%B' HEAD)
# I use zsh so $0 works for me. In bash BASH_SOURCE is correct
TOP=$(realpath $(dirname $0)/../../../..)

GIT_INDEX_FILE_SAV=$GIT_INDEX_FILE
unset GIT_INDEX_FILE
git --git-dir .git --work-tree . -C ${TOP} commit sub -m "${COMMIT_MSG}"
GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE_SAV
```

When the hook is called, we are in the middle of `git commit` in the submodule, so various `GIT*` environment variables are set according to the submodule repo.  We need to reset them and let git use values from the parent repo.

[Edit] A better way to populate `$TOP` is

```sh
TOP=$(git rev-parse --show-superproject-working-tree)
```

Thanks to @phd for suggesting it.

Comment: [`TOP=$(git rev-parse --show-superproject-working-tree)`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt---show-superproject-working-tree)